# What is the correct measure word for 问题 (question)?

Tags: writing, measure-word

I'm not sure if I should say 一件问题 or 一项问题. I know I can get away with 一个问题, but I'd like to know the "correct" measure word.

Note: I would like to use the tag measure-word, but I can't. I used "writing" instead, because using the right measure word (instead of 个) seems to only matter in writing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the standard measure words for 问题:

- Normally you would use 个.
- If there is a stream of questions you can use 串, for example 一大串问题.
- If there are a couple of questions, you can use 些
- If you are talking about kinds of questions, you have to use 类, for example   这类问题 (this kind of problem)

件 is used, but not very often, even in writing. 项 is not a standard measure word for 问题, but it can be used when talking about problems (for example software problems), not when talking about questions.

Comment: Both 一件问题 and 一项问题 can be understood but sound awkward to me. IMO these usages should be avoided. Otherwise it's a great answer.

Comment: @NS.X.: I completely agree for 一件问题, but a sentence similar to 新固件修正六项问题 is quite common when talking about problems (for example in hardware and software).

Comment: you're right, in that specific context it sounds good, not in spoken language though.

Comment: The 问题 in 新固件修正六项问题 is not "questions" but more like "issues". That's the reason they have different measure words.

Comment: @AngelLeliel: That's what I also wrote: "it can be used when talking about problems (for example software problems), not when talking about question"

Answer (score 5):

The correct measure word or (量词) for 问题 is 个 as in 一个问题. There is no explanation for this, and the knowledge is only acquired through practice.

- 项 is a measure word for 工程
- 件 is a measure word for 事情

Other measure words include:

- 一尊佛像 (a statue, unit word describes a statue)
- 一顶帽子 (a hat)
- 一只猫 (a cat)
- 一打鸡蛋 (a dozen of eggs)
- 一条蛇 (a snake)
- 一串葡萄 (a bunch of grapes)

For more examples, please refer to [Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8F%E8%A9%9E) or [Baidu](http://baike.baidu.com/view/633608.htm) article on the topic of 量词.

Answer (score 1):

The correct measure word for 问题 is 道。